# Плагин или настройка в VS Code для автоматического проставления скобок у функций Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Подскажите, п-та, есть ли в VS Code плагин или внутренняя настройка для автоматического проставления скобок у функций Python после их ввода (как в Pycharm)? По умолчанию приходится их сейчас писать руками.

Comment: писать руками - это нормально. крепитесь. а так, поисковик - по другому адресу.

Comment: python.analysis.completeFunctionParens - вспомнил :) В settings.json данному параметру выставляем true.